# Determining Min and Max Values SQL Query Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have a DE that lists of all ads on site.

That data includes, maker, model and listing price.

What I am trying to do is query out the following information:

- distinct model
- maker
- the min list price
- the max list price

I can query out model and make with no problem to a new DE...and get 20,008 records:

```
select DISTINCT b.[Listing_Model__c], b.[Listing_Make__c]
From Web_Information__c_Salesforce as b
```

When I try to pull in the min and max values, it's not working. Here is what I have tried (I'm using the convert operator because the list price is set as a text not a numeric field):

```
select CONVERT(numeric,'MIN(b.Listing_Price__c)') as 'MinListPrice', CONVERT(numeric,'MAX(b.Listing_Price__c)') as 'MaxListPrice'
From "Web_Information__c_Salesforce" as b

INNER JOIN "FSBO-MakeModels" as c
on
b.[Listing_Make__c] = c.[Listing_Make__c] and
b.[Listing_Model__c] = c.[Listing_Model__c]
```

It's only giving me 1 record... What I want is the min and max listing prices for those 20,008 different Make/Models.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Is the Listing_Price_c field a number value? or does it have special characters like commas and dollar signs?

Comment: it's not a number field right now, it's a text field - using MIN and MAX will give me a character count, and if I could get that to work right now I'd be happy, LOL

Answer (score 1):

**Issue**: You are using aggregate functions that are running the MAX and MIN for **Every Model and Make** . This is is why it is returning a single value.

**Solution**: A possible way to go about this will be to order the rows in a sub query and select the top and bottom from it.

Try this:

```
**/*Query 1 -DE 1*/**
select DISTINCT b.[Listing_Model__c], b.[Listing_Make__c]
From Web_Information__c_Salesforce as b
```

**/* Query 2 -DE 2 */**

```
 SELECT


 [Listing_Model__c]

 [Listing_Make__c]

 ,Listing_Price__c as MinlistPrice

 FROM


( SELECT 

 b.[Listing_Model__c]

 ,b.[Listing_Make__c]

 ,b.[Listing_Price__c] 

 ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY b.[Listing_Model__c] ORDER BY CAST('b.Listing_Price__c' as INT) ASC  ) as row

 FROM 

 Web_Information__c_Salesforce b ) x

WHERE x.row = 1
```

**/* Query 3 -DE 3 */**

```
 SELECT
 Listing_Model__c]

 ,[Listing_Make__c]

 ,Listing_Price__c as MaxlistPrice

 FROM

( SELECT 

 b.[Listing_Model__c]

 ,b.[Listing_Make__c]

 ,b.[Listing_Price__c] 

 ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY b.[Listing_Model__c] ORDER BY CAST('b.Listing_Price__c' as INT) DESC  ) as row

 FROM 

 Web_Information__c_Salesforce b ) x

WHERE x.row = 1
```

**/* Query 4 - DE 4 */**

```
SELECT

a.[Listing_Model__c]
,a.[Listing_Make__c]
,MaxlistPrice
,MinlistPrice

FROM [DE 1] a INNER JOIN [DE 2] b ON  a.[Listing_Model__c] = b.[Listing_Model__c]
AND a.[Listing_Make__c] = b.[Listing_Make__c]

INNER JOIN [DE 3] c ON  a.[Listing_Model__c] = c.[Listing_Model__c]
AND a.[Listing_Make__c] = c.[Listing_Make__c]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66163/discussion-on-answer-by-data-kid-determining-min-and-max-values-sql-query-salesf).

Comment: Thanks for moving it to chat, I posted further comments in there.

Comment: @user2322059 updated